# Testing Observable.zip subscription

Tags: angular, testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine, observable

I have an Observable.zip() on which i subscribe
It looks something like this:

```
 public awesomeMethod(){
   this.someObservable
    .zip(
     observable1,
     observable2,
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
     this.newData = data;
   }
 });
}
```

And i'd like to test this:

```
const zipObservable = Observable.of(data);

spyOn(component.zipObservable,'zip').and.returnValue(zipObservable);
component.awesomeMethod();
```

I need to know when the subscription has been called so i can if `this.newData` is what i expect.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Can't help you on that but maybe this article might : https://blog.nrwl.io/controlling-time-with-zone-js-and-fakeasync-f0002dfbf48c

Comment: You spyOn the Observable, but the Observable is never going to see the data you want to see: the Observable defines the data flow, but it is not responsible for sending the values, that is the job of the Observer's which are created when you subscribe. The article linked by Maxime uses Promises, but you use Rxjs. See for example this: https://blog.hyphe.me/rxjs-testing-in-real-world-applications/